# Why URL that reach specific port in front got https?

Tags: port, https

Some web hosting control panel must use URL https://example.com:3500 to reach it. If I do not type https, browser will not reach it.

HTTPS is port 443. Is it port 3500 or port 443?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **both**.  They are running an SSL web site on port 3500.  That's why *both* protocol (https) and port (3500) have to be specified. *http* is the wrong protocol; and 443 (the default port) is the wrong port.

Comment: It is means that the URL is using https protocol on port 3500. It is not using port 443. Am I correct?